# Html to PDF Conversion in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, pdf-generation, nuget-package

Is there any open source NuGet package or library which converts `HTML` to `PDF` for `Xamarin.Forms`?

`HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp` does the job but It is not supported for `Android`.

Any free ones or any suggestions to create a renderer which does the conversion?

Comment: why don' t you write dependency service for each platform

Comment: Yes, I think that should be the only option as I am not finding the `Xamarin.Forms` library for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check Syncfusion, they have a community license.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7218/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-xamarin-platform